# Python returns instance instead of array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, instance

The structure of my program is simple. I have two `.py` files, say `file1.py` and `file2.py`. `file1` is UI, `file2` is calculations. When a button is pressed, `file1` sends the user input to `file2` and `file2` does calculations and then it is supposed to return an array to `file1` so that `file1` can plot it in the field embedded in the UI.

Both .py files work without any problems when I put a `plt.plot(...)` code in `file2` and run my program that way, window pops up with my plot in it.

Now the issue is when I do things like below, I'll try to give you a sample code showing my approach at this:

Below is the last method in file2>

```
class Calculations:
    def calcFunc(self, some arg):
        """do calculations"""
        return self.resultingArray
```

Below code is in file1, typical gui stuff so I'm cropping out some parts>

```
import file2
class Application:
    def onButtonAction(self, *user info*):
        """do stuff here"""
        self.myPlotData = file2.Calculations(*user info*)
        print type(self.myPlotData)
```

When I do this, shell prints this on my screen:

```
<calcs.Calculations instance at blah>
```

I check the type of the data that returns because in my previous attempts at plotting that data, I received some matplotlib errors so I googled and saw there was something wrong so I decided that I'd check the type of the data that is returned. So I am just stuck here and would absolutely appreciate any help on this.

Note: `self.resultingArray` is a numpy array, I checked. When I just go and end that part of the code with `print self.resultingArray`, it prints and `type(self.resultingArray)` returns numpy array. As I said, plt.plot() also works but I need to make it return that data properly so I can put that plot in my UI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't it be something like: print type(self.myPlotData.calcfunc(yourArgs))

Comment: Did you mean to put `file2.Calculations.calcFunc(args)`?  As it stands, you're just constructing an instance of the class, not actually running the function (unless it's part of your constructor, but then, you're not actually getting the `return`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Calculations` is a class, this line invokes the implicit constructor:

```
self.myPlotData = file2.Calculations(*user info*)
```

And you should know that the result of a constructor is an instance of the class. Which is exactly why you are getting that `type` information.

If you actually want `myPlotData` to be an array, then invoke `calcFunc()` from a `Calculations` instance. For example:

```
self.myCalculations = file2.Calculations()
self.myPlotData = self.myCalculations.calcFunc(*user info*)
```

Comment: So do you say there isn't a way of doing this by passing arguments to file2 via `file2.Calculations.__init__` ? My `file2.Calculations.__init__` accepts `*user info*` and things go from there. Since I can't do it invoking the implicit constructor, it looks like I'll have to change the structure of my methods. Thank you for your quick answer and I would appreciate your further comments on this.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, I changed the __init__ method and after a very small arrangement following your comment, it worked. Thanks a lot Chris.